# Receiving a Resource Exhausted error when running RLHF tuning job

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to test running a basic RLHF tuning job using the rlhf-train-template (stable) pipeline. Each time I try to run the job I get the following error at the Reward Model Trainer step:

```
com.google.cloud.ai.platform.common.errors.AiPlatformException: code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, message=The following quota metrics exceed quota limits: aiplatform.googleapis.com/restricted_image_training_a2_cpus, cause=null; Failed to create custom job.Project number: 433628020382, Job id: 989102518405431296, Task id: -1044677471070322688, Task name: rewardmodeltrainer, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/433628020382/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default/executions/4410343601922198283; Failed to create external task or refresh its state. Task:Project number: 433628020382, Job id: 989102518405431296, Task id: -1044677471070322688, Task name: rewardmodeltrainer, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/433628020382/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default/executions/4410343601922198283; Failed to handle the pipeline task. Task: Project number: 433628020382, Job id: 989102518405431296, Task id: -1044677471070322688, Task name: rewardmodeltrainer, Task state: DRIVER_SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/433628020382/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default/executions/4410343601922198283
```

[Screenshot of above error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWzUT.png)

Here is the content of my human preference dataset in JSONL format:

```
{"input_text": "What is 2+2?","candidate_0": "4","candidate_1": "5","choice": 0}
{"input_text": "What is 3x7?","candidate_0": "10","candidate_1": "21","choice": 1}
{"input_text": "What is 2 to the power of 4?","candidate_0": "8","candidate_1": "16","choice": 1}
```

Here is the content of my prompt dataset in JSONL format:

```
{"input_text": "What is 2+2?"}
{"input_text": "What is 3x7?"}
{"input_text": "What is 2 to the power of 4?"}
```

I have increased my "Restricted image training CPUs for A2 CPU types per region" quota to 64 for the region `us-central1` and expected this to fix the error but it has not resolved.